# Get color of selected pixel in matlab GUI imscrollpanel

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm using a `imscrollpanel` to show a scrolled image with Matlab GUI. Is it possible to get color of image pixel by clicking on `imscrollpanel`?

Comment: Are you looking for impixel ? (Needed: Image processing/analysis toolbox)

Comment: No, I just want to implement a functionality to get image pixel color by clicking on it's container